# NEO4J count filter nodes with less then X connections

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have the following query:

```
MATCH(cw:commonWords)-[theEdge]->(story:theStory) 
WHERE cw.text IN ['tools','sell'] RETURN cw,story
```

I want to filter out all the `story` nodes (blue) that have less then 2 incoming connections.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One option is:

```
MATCH(cw:commonWords)-[theEdge]->(story:theStory)
WHERE cw.text IN ['tools','sell']
WITH collect(cw) AS cws, story
WHERE size(cws) > 1
UNWIND cws AS cw
RETURN cw, story
```

Which with this sample data:

```
MERGE (a1:commonWords {text: 'tools'})  
MERGE (a2:commonWords {text: 'sell'}) 
MERGE (b1:theStory {key: 4756})
MERGE (b2:theStory {key: 4753}) 
MERGE (b3:theStory {key: 4752}) 
MERGE (b4:theStory {key: 4755}) 

MERGE (a1)-[:commonWordsInStory]-(b1)
MERGE (a2)-[:commonWordsInStory]-(b1)
MERGE (a1)-[:commonWordsInStory]-(b2)
MERGE (a2)-[:commonWordsInStory]-(b2)
MERGE (a1)-[:commonWordsInStory]-(b3)
MERGE (a2)-[:commonWordsInStory]-(b3)
MERGE (a1)-[:commonWordsInStory]-(b4)
```

Returns:

```
╒════════════════╤════════════╕
│"cw"            │"story"     │
╞════════════════╪════════════╡
│{"text":"tools"}│{"key":4756}│
├────────────────┼────────────┤
│{"text":"sell"} │{"key":4756}│
├────────────────┼────────────┤
│{"text":"tools"}│{"key":4753}│
├────────────────┼────────────┤
│{"text":"sell"} │{"key":4753}│
├────────────────┼────────────┤
│{"text":"tools"}│{"key":4752}│
├────────────────┼────────────┤
│{"text":"sell"} │{"key":4752}│
└────────────────┴────────────┘
```

Answer (score 0):

To filter out `story` nodes with less than 2 incoming `commonWordsInStory` relationships (and return each resulting `story` along with a list of its common words):

```
MATCH (cw:commonWords)-[:commonWordsInStory]->(story:theStory) 
WHERE cw.text IN ['tools', 'sell']
WITH story, COLLECT(cw) AS commonWords
WHERE SIZE(commonWords) > 1
RETURN story, commonWords
```

If you want to return each common word in a separate row, just replace the above `RETURN` clause with:

```
...
UNWIND commonWords AS commonWord
RETURN story, commonWord
```